# Jquery .focusout not working on mobile(slicknav)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

Slicknav only closes if you click the menu button again.

so I did this bit of code to make it close when you click anywhere

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   //close menu on lost focus
   $('.slicknav_menu').focusout(function(event){
      $('.menu').slicknav('close');
   });  
});
```

This works on desktop when I make my window small to test, but on phone i have to touch an image for it to close, not if i just click anywhere, its like it only registers a click if you touch an element.

Can i use somethign else instead of focusout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed using

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#whole-page').click(function(event) { 
      $('.menu').slicknav('close');
   });

});
```

I couldn't use body as the menu was in the body and the menu closed straight after opening it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a normal click event on the body and check if what the user clicked was inside the slicknav_menu.

```
$('body').click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.slicknav_menu').length) {
       $('.menu').slicknav('close');
    }        
});
```

Comment: doesn't even close on desktop with this

Comment: So when you click outside it's passing the logic of 'if' clause?  

We would need to see more of the generated html structure to find out why.

Comment: my code works on desktop, i need something that recognises a touch as a click